# How to change UIBarButtonItem tint color for MFMailComposeViewController when presented automatically from UITextView

Tags: ios, swift

I know when I manually present mailComposeViewController I can do it like this:

```
mailComposeViewController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

but since the controller is presented out of my control because in `UITextView` an email was detected... it cannot be changed this way:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
```

The above solution doesnt work. It is still blue. How can I customize it?

Comment: When are you saying the `appearance` stuff?

Comment: `application:didFinishLaunching`...

Comment: I was afraid of that... :(

Comment: Should it be somewhere else?

Comment: No, that's the right place. That's the problem. If that doesn't work, maybe there is just a bug where the appearance proxy doesn't work here. You might try appearanceWhenContainedIn, I suppose... But I don't hold out much hope. This view controller may be out of process.

Comment: What if you implement the UITextViewDelegate method so that you intervene and present the mail compose view controller yourself??

Comment: How? How can I detect that `UITextView` did detect an email and is about to present email controller?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1649337-textview